# Detecting if it is the first time a user access some pages in Moodle 2.7 to show him that something changed on the interface

Tags: javascript, php, user-interface, moodle

Here are my limitations for this task:

- For Moodle 2.7
- I cannot install any plugin
- I cannot create any plugin

So I need to identify if a user is accessing some pages on Moodle for the first time after an interface update to show them what is new. I would like do something like Google does when it updates its pages.

> 'Ow, what is new? this, this and that. Okay? End of story and you will
>   never see me again.'

I identified the 'Object' '**$USER**' in the file '**columns3.php**' which is in the folder '**layout**'.
This '**$USER**' provides lots of information to be used and maybe it could be useful for me.

Is it possible to use any information from the refered 'Objet' in order allow me to show the contextual help for a user only once? Or, is there any other place I can find some data I could use for my purpose?

The contextual help which will present what is new is going to run via front-end files and is already ready to be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the following approach:
On any of the pages where that interface is going to run, make a query to the `mdl_log` table, with following condition:

1. That the `userid` column  value = $USER->id
2. That the `url` column value = what ever possible url where that interface is used.
3. And that `time` column value > than date when you updated that 
   interface

If that query returns 0 results, then it means user has not visited that page since the time you installed it so show your notice box or whatever, otherwise don't show your notice box.

Another possible approach would be to make the verification right there on the interface's code, so that whenever it is used it would check:

1. Has current `$USER->id invoked` this code before? (You can add a
   boolean field to the `mdl_user` table and simple store there a value
   (1 or 0) to track if user has used the interface after the update).
2. Declare a global `$VISITED` variable and asign the appropiate value depending on results of step 1, to later be used
    on your php view code(the html)
3. In you php html file do: `(If $VISITED == 0) THEN show_notice_box ELSE do nothing`